# pygame.font.SysFont() takes about 5 seconds on macOS

Tags: python, fonts, pygame, pygame2

I'm using `pygame 2.0.0.dev15` to develop games with Python. Everything works great so far, but I'm surprised that `pygame.font.SysFont()` takes a lot of time to process.

Whenever I use fonts in my game, the startup takes about 5 seconds more than without them. The number of fonts I use doesn't seem to slow it down - it's just that first `pygame.font.SysFont()` call doing that. Something is definitely wrong. I'm on macOS Catalina, using Python 3.8.6.

The problem is gone when I use `pygame.font.Font()` instead.

Why does `pygame.font.SysFont()` take so much time?

Comment: Maybe it's worth raising an issue - https://github.com/pygame/pygame/issues

Answer (score -2):

It is because different operating systems have different speeds.